# How to obtain the maximum/minimum longitude and latitude for a polygon?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, polygon, latitude-longitude

I have the MSA/CMSA shapefile which contains 274 metropolitan areas. How do I have to obtain the maximum/minimum longitude and latitude **for an area**?

So, it's like drawing a box right outside and getting the 4 corner points in the lon/lat format.

Can we do this using Python to iterate the process for all the cities and to export the coordinates to a text file as follows?:

```
msa     min_lon   max_lon   min_lat  max_lat
6162   -76.XXXX  -74.XXXX   38.XXXX  40.XXXX
9094   -97.XXXX  -96.XXXX   37.XXXX  38.XXXX
....
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, the shape's `.extent` property is all you need.

```
with open('out.txt', 'wb') as out_text_file, arcpy.da.SearchCursor('path_to_data', ('msa', 'SHAPE@')) as cur:
    print >>out_text_file, "msa     min_lon   max_lon   min_lat  max_lat"
    for row in cur:
        msa, ext = row[0], row[1].extent
        print >>out_text_file, "{0:5}   {1:2.4}   {2:2.4}   {3:2.4}   {4:2.4}".format(msa, ext.XMin, ext.XMax, ext.YMin, ext.YMax)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did like "{0:4} {1:2.10} {2:2.10} {3:2.10} {4:2.10}". Sorry but how to print things line by line? It looks like: sacmsa min_lon max_lon min_lat max_lat
3605 1648730.629 1706965.272 -179218.143 -120887.8656
4880 -260536.0373 -187164.4402 -1272776.399 -1190140.498
7920 208472.9416 291854.6719 -73215.75796 2990.560084
6280 1288788.431 1425130.378 364249.6568 527714.2303
3362 -18462.7105 159514.9954 -967557.6621 -767405.1027
1602 579024.2094 753153.3687 417992.4495 .........

Comment: Try putting \n on the last line immediately before the second double quote.

Comment: Adding \n does not work. 
 
 
Another question: The liner unit is in meters as you see the numbers I posted earlier. How can I change them to decimal degrees in ArcGIS? The current projection is USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic. And its unit is meter.

Comment: Read the help for [arcpy.da.SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000). You can pass a geographic spatial reference and the coordinates will be output in lon/lat.